# Limpiar input label dentro de un DIV?

Tags: php, jquery

Estimados, saludos a todos! Quizás es un poco básico, pero prefiero estar seguro y preguntar.

Tengo un `div` en cual tengo ordenados varios `input`, alguno de ellos `label`, en los cuales hago referencia a un `input file`, de esta manera;

```
<table class="title">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 20%" >
            <input class="" value="1" type="checkbox" name="tipo_cert[]" id="tipo_cert_1" />
            <label for="tipo_cert_1">Para subir archivo</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/><br/>
<div id="arch1" style="display: none;">
  <div id='file1' class="file">
    <input type="hidden" class="txtFile1" name="txtFile1" value="" />
    <label class="text" id='text1' for="6_1_adjn">Seleccione un archivo</label>
    <label for="6_1_adjn" >
        <input id="6_1_adjn" name="6_1_adjn"  class='fileInput required' type="file" value="" />    
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Mediante un `checkbox`, hago aparecer y desaparecer un `div` que contiene este código. Entonces al hacer clic en este `checkbox` y desaparecer esto, se debieran limpiar todos los input de este `div`. Y es ahí en donde estoy pegado. Limpio el `hidden`, logro desmarcar los `checkbox` pero no logro limpiar el `label` y si le coloco un `.val('')` al `input file` me dice: 'security issue', por ende con el `input file` no me voy a meter =) jaja

Mi código JS;

```
$('#tipo_cert_1').on('change', function () {
  if ($('#tipo_cert_1').is(':checked') == true) {
    $("#arch1").attr('style', 'display: block;');
  }else{
    $("#arch1").attr('style', 'display: none;');

    $("#arch1 input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);
    // $("#arch1 input[type=label]").text("");
    // $("#arch1 input:label").text("");

  }
});
```

Ahora, ¿afecta el que este `label` este dentro de un `div` que esta dentro de otro `div`? Una pregunta que quizás es la razón por la cual no puedo limpiar o llegar a este `label`.

Estimados, esta es mi inquietud. Una vez un profesor me dijo que la única pregunta TONTA, es la que no se hace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los `label` no son un tipo de `input`, son HTML tags como cualquier otro, si quieres cambiarles de nombre a los `label` simplemente úsalos como cualquier otro tag:

```
$("#arch1 label").text("");
```

Ten en cuenta que lo anterior cambiará el texto de todos los `label`. Si quieres usar alguno en específico puedes usar el `id`, la clase o aprovechar el artibuto `for` del `label`:

```
$("#arch1 #text1").text("");
$("#arch1 label.text").text("");
$("#arch1 label[for=6_1_adjn]").text("");
```

> Ahora, afecta el que este label este dentro de un div que esta dentro de otro div?

No, la búsqueda la realiza con respecto a todos los "hijos" de `#arch1`

Comment: Estimado, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente me limpia los 'tags' `label` (ahora si..jaja). 
Ahora puedo hacer alguna referencia con las clases de los `label`; por ejemplo con el `class='text'` del `label`??

Comment: @x_Mario claro, si quieres cambiar a todos los label que tengan la clase `text` puedes usar `$("#arch1 .text").text("")`

Comment: MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS! @César.. seguiré con las pruebas..
AGRADECIDO!!

Comment: @x_Mario de nada, si te ayudó, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada para cerrar la pregunta. Saludos